# Dividing in integers wider than a single register assemby

Tags: assembly, integer, precision, division, arbitrary-precision

How to divide two **signed** 64 bit numbers on a 32 bit architecture?

I'm not asking for any code, just an algorithm I can implement. Let's assume that I have available instructions for unsigned and signed division (`div` and `idiv`).

I'm open to dividing by subtracting, if it can be done that way.  It needs to work for signed numbers.

(editor's note: the first version of this question used the term "double precision", hence the comments asking for clarification on floating point vs. BigInteger).

Comment: Divide by subtracting? How long will that take to divide 9223372036854775807 by 3? I would use a shift and compare/subtract, similar to the way you do it for decimal on paper, but binary (adjust negative values before and after).

Comment: But... do you mean two **floating point** double Precision or two 64 bits integers? The former is trivial.

Comment: I meant integers. Sorry if it is trivial, but kinda new in assembly.

Comment: Maybe this may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884172/algorithm-for-dividing-very-large-numbers

Comment: I think this might help. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the https://gmplib.org/ source code to see how they do it, if you're curious.  Note that x86's 32bit operand-size `div` instruction is a 64b / 32b => 32b operation, but it faults if the quotient doesn't fit in 32bit.  (Another interesting question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085162/overcoming-the-x86-idiv-de-exception)

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: See Knuth Volume 2 section 4.3.1 Algorithm D.